# Clash Royale cards shuffle

Tags: clash-royale

I know that the card once used gets added to a queue in the backend. However, what I don't understand is what algorithm has been used to shuffle cards at the beginning of the game. 
Can anyone explain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cards you draw at the start of a match are completely random. It doesn't matter how you initially arranged the cards in your deck, or what types of cards your deck consists of.

Per the [Clash Royale wiki](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Basics_of_Battle):

> In battle, 4 of the 8 cards in your Battle Deck will be available to play in most cases. The first 4 cards will be randomly selected at the start of the battle.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely not true.  Having battled against higher level cards since the beginning I have come up with a deck that does well when underpowered.  The deck revolves around the golem, and I can assure you it is not random.  I noticed it a lot when I got to level 12 cards and was constantly playing all max cards.  If the golem is 7 or 8 I have such a slow start it is hard to recover.  So I started tracking where the card starts. Less than 1/3 of the time (47 out of my last 152 matches) is the card in the starting four.  This simply is not random.